# Decrypt AES-256-GCM TLS 1.2 encrypted packets, I have the key but I don't have the IV can I still decrypt?

Tags: decryption, wireshark

Can I decrypt AES-256-GCM TLS 1.2 encrypted packets, I have the key but I don't have the IV can I still decrypt? I am getting these packets from wireshark. I know that the IV might be at the front of the encrypted text and its size is probably 12 bytes but I don't know how to get it from the encrypted text.

Comment: GCM has no IV, mostly if people speak of on IV for GCM they just have reused that name to supply the nonce (see [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/71216/744)). The nonce is also public and therefore my be prepended to the cipher text. Note that the nonce has a variable length and not a fixed like an IV. But if you don't have the nonce GCM decryption is as far as I know not possible.

Comment: If you have the key, just let Wireshark decrypt it.. It knows what part of the packet is the IV/nonce.

Comment: where could I input the key in wireshark?